# The prefix "xmnls" for attribute "xmnls:mvc" associated with an element type "beans" is not bound

Tags: xml, spring-mvc

Error * The prefix "xmnls" for attribute "xmnls:mvc" associated with an element type "beans" is not bound.
        please Help me..Thanks in advance.*

```
This is my Spring-Dispatcher-Servlet.xml

        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmnls:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


           <context:component-scan base-package="com.gontu.Annotation.Helloexample"></context:component-scan>
           <mvc:annotation-driven/>

           <bean id = "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
           <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
           </property>
              <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
           </property>
           </bean>
           </beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
       xmnls:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         ^^
```

to

```
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         ^^
```